# Cannot read property addclass of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I pass a dom node along with a classname to a directive where the directive then will add class to the passed dom element. I get an error Cannot read property addclass of undefined. Please have a look at the plnkr. https://plnkr.co/edit/kT37XoeMWMZ7qexwZ15W?p=preview

```
export class App implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
   }

    @ViewChild(changeStyleClass) vc: changeStyleClass;
    @ViewChild('h1Ref') h1: el;
    @ViewChild('mbc') mbc: el;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.vc.addClass(this.h1.nativeElement, 'redColor');
    this.vc.addClass(this.mbc.nativeElement, 'makeBorder');
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to add the html side of this component in the question

Comment: That will be the part of the answer. Please check the plunkr

Comment: you need to provide a [mcve] here and not in a link

Comment: Thats the working plunkr with minimal code

Answer (score 1):

Apply your directive to DOM elements.

```
<h1 changeStyleClass #h1Ref>change this to green color</h1>
<p changeStyleClass #mbc>make border class</p>
```

**Edit**

Instead of creating a ViewChild reference for a directive. You can also use nativeElement.classList to add and remove classes on the element directly too.

```
@ViewChild('h1Ref') h1: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('mbc') mbc: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.h1.nativeElement.classList.add('makeBorder');
  this.h1.nativeElement.classList.add('redColor');

  this.mbc.nativeElement.classList.add('makeBorder');
  this.mbc.nativeElement.classList.add('redColor');
}
```

Comment: sorry thats incorrect. check this plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/5Htzsl0jp4ZdKeqrkAlU?p=preview
The p tag doesnt work by that way

Comment: I realized the problem, This was because vc was only referring to first instance of ViewChild() defined in the component. Check my edited answer. :)

Comment: I wanted to pass without a reference.

Comment: I just checked the first example is working correctly. It was not working in the plunkr because you had the wrong order actually. In your example you declared view child before directive declaration on the DOM. If you write <h1 changeStyleClass #h1Ref>change this to green color</h1> instead of <h1  #h1Ref changeStyleClass>change this to green color</h1> It won't work